# Дискорд бот работает только в основном канале, как исправить?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть довольно кривой дискорд бот и он выдает/забирает роль у человека при введении команды, но работает эта команда только в одном канале (общее). Как сделать что бы он работал везде? В чем у меня ошибка?

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ""

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('.'))
client.remove_command( 'help' )

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print("Я запущен!")

@client.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
   await ctx.send('Hi')

@client.command( pass_context = True )
async def clear( ctx, amount = 1000 ):
await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount)


@client.command()

async def кухня(ctx, member: discord.Member):
   role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 981594840879988807)
   if role in ctx.author.roles:
       await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
   else:
       await ctx.author.add_roles(role)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.channel.id == 981574989801205776:
       embed = discord.Embed(
           title='Новое сообщение',
           description=f'{message.content}\nАвтор: {message.author}',
           color=0xFF0033
       )

       await client.get_channel(981574989801205777).send(embed=embed)
       await client.process_commands(message)



client.run(TOKEN) ```
````

Comment: Что именно у вас не работает? Выдача роли или отправка эмбеда с текстом сообщения и автором?

Comment: У меня не работают команды во всех текстовых каналах кроме одного и мне нужно это как-то решить. Роль выдается и забирается нормально

Comment: Они работают только в канале, у которого id 981574989801205776?

Comment: Да, только в нем работает. Видимо эта часть @client.event с переадресацией сообщений блокирует доступ к другим каналам, но это копирование сообщений мне еще будет необходимо..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выше в комментариях я у вас уточнил где работают команды, а где нет. Попробуйте этот код.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

   await client.process_commands(message)

   if message.channel.id == 981574989801205776:
       embed = discord.Embed(
           title='Новое сообщение',
           description=f'{message.content}\nАвтор: {message.author}',
           color=0xFF0033
       )

       await client.get_channel(981574989801205777).send(embed=embed)
```